# How to use conditional #error

Tags: c, error-handling, compiler-errors, pragma, build-error

I have a an application header file in c where I mention the variable.

```
#VAR_X        "testData"
```

User can change this variable  but I want to restrict it's length to maximum of 50.If user tries to make it more than 50 there should be an error on building the code.

I have done like this in the application.h:

```
#define __IS_MORE            if((strlen(VAR_X) - 50) > 0) 1:0;
```

and in application.c at the top .

```
#define application.h
#if defined(__IS_MORE)
#error "Size is more than the maximum size"
#endif
```

But no matter what I put in the VAR I always get the #error directive "Size is more than the maximum size"

What wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At compile time, you can do this by using a technique called as static assert. you can find the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c). Assuming a STATIC_ASSERT macro is defined as explained in the link, you can do the following to check if VAR_X exceeds the length (Here I assume that VAR_X is a macro as in #define VAR_X "...")

```
STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(VAR_X) <= 50, "Size of VAR_X is more than the maximum size");
```

Some example code

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(COND,MSG) typedef char static_assertion_##MSG[(COND)?1:-1]
#define VAR_X "012345678912912"

STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(VAR_X) <= 50, Size_of_VAR_X_is_more_than_the_maximum_size);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: doesn't seems to be working.Or am I missing something here.Is "sizeof" also expands into some macro?

Comment: A macro is replaced with its contents by pre-processor. Compiler sees it as sizeof("testData") and does not know about the macro expansion. I have copy pasted some example working code.

Answer (score 1):

`#define` and `#if` are part of the C preprocessor and are evaluated before compiling the code.

The line `#if defined(__IS_MORE)` simply evaluates if the label `__IS_MORE` has been defined, which it has. Therefore the `#error` is processed.

What you are wanting to do (make sure that programmer can't define `VAR_X` with more than 50 characters) can not be done at the preprocessor level. The best you can do is put a run time check at the start of the code if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

`#ifdef` (and `#if defined(..)`) are precompiler checks and are true if the symbol is defined at the point the code is compiled.

It doesn't matter *WHAT* you define `#define __IS_MORE` as, the macro *IS* defined as something, hence the error.

As your check requires evaluation of `strlen` at run time, you could look instead at a construct like [`assert`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571340/what-is-the-assert-function) to enforce your check.