# How can I Overload [ ] Operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, overloading, operator-keyword

How can I overload the [ ] operator in c++.  I basically want to access the index of  One-D array and return it. I tried doing this but it doesn't seem to produce the desired result.

```
Square Square::operator [](const Square& temp)
{
   Square obj; //creates a Square class object.

  for(int i=0;i<dimension;i++)
    {
       *obj.board = temp.board[i];

    }
return obj;

}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using [] as a copy operator that return a new object. What you want is something that gets an index, i, and returns this.board[i]. assuming this.board exists.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). You bug might be elsewhere (also having `temp`, that is the index, being a `Square` looks strange)

Comment: If `Square` contains the array you want to access, then you basically want a pass-through operator that acts like `operator[]` for normal arrays.  That means it should take an index, return a reference to the actual array's element type, and use the array's `operator[]` internally.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an array of sorts in your `Square` class then your subscript overload would look something like this

```
Square& Square::operator[] (const int index)
{
   // checks if index is >= to zero AND less than your array size
   assert(index >= 0 && index < yourArray.size());
   return yourArray[index];
}
```

More info on [assert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1571360/4962554)

**PS: This works under the assumption that you'll create an array of `Square`. If not, then update the method signature respectively.**

Comment: Recommend a quick explanation of what assert does and probably a link to a reputable documentation page for more details.