# Assert Keyword in C

Tags: c, keyword

Other than the textbook definitions of the keyword 'assert' 
What is the actual use case ?

Its not a commonly used keyword so examples are rare to find explaining the actual implementation and its use in Code

Comment: `assert()` is a macro, not a keyword.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571340/what-is-the-assert-function

Comment: A common use case is to check if a memory allocation routine, e.g. `malloc` was successful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "assert" function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571340/what-is-the-assert-function)

Comment: @bruceg yes, a common **absolutely incorrect** use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it in any way you may find suitable.
Personally, I use it for writing simple unit tests when I don't want to rely on any dependency.

Some people use it for checking pre and post-conditions, like for example:

```
int foo(int a, int b) {
    int result;

    assert(a > 0 && a < 150);
    assert(b > 20 && b < 1000);

    // do something with a, b and store something in result

    assert(result > -10 && result < 10);

    return result;
}
```

But please beware that assertions can be disabled at compile time by defining the `NDEBUG` macro.
So for example if you rely on it for pre-conditions, you may want to double them with tests built un-conditionally.