# how should I use assert in Dart?

Tags: dart

I saw exmaple code something like:

```
class ModelBinding extends StatefulWidget {
  ModelBinding({
    Key key,
    this.initialModel = const GalleryOptions(),
    this.child,
  })  : assert(initialModel != null),
        super(key: key);
...
```

so I wrote something:

```
class Person {
  String firstName;

  Person({name}){
   print(name);
  }
}

class Employee extends Person {
  Employee(String name) : assert(false), super(name: name);
}

main() {
  var emp = new Employee('Jason');
}
```

No matter if it is `assert(false)` or `assert(true)`, the result is same.

So what is the meaning of `assert`?

Comment: It's the same as in other programming languages (e.g. [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python), [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571340/what-is-the-assert-function), [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758224/what-does-the-java-assert-keyword-do-and-when-should-it-be-used), ...).  You aren't seeing any effect because you're probably running a release-build of your code where assertions aren't enabled.  Run a debug build instead.

Answer (score 2):

`assert` is used for debugging and it simply means the condition should be `true` to proceed. Let me explain:

```
class MyClass {
  final int age;

  MyClass({this.age});

  void someMethod() {
    // using `age` here
  }
}
```

You might face issues in `someMethod` if `age` passed is `null`, so to make sure it isn't `null`, you use `assert` like:

```
class MyClass {
  final int age;

  MyClass({this.age}) : assert(age != null, "Make sure age isn't null");

  void someMethod() {
    // using `age` here
  }
}
```

Comment: What If I don't put assert check there? I eventually will get the error for null `age` inside `someMethod` and will find the problem and will handle the null value to not get it in the production mode! (because I'll get null related exception eventually inside the method). So I could handle without assert! What is the usage of assert as a whole I can't figure out!!! The thing is I check the errors in debug mode using assert but the checks are useless in production mode. So instead of writing those assert checks I can check the nulls! Hope you get where I have problem.

Comment: @Patzu `assert` only works in the debug mode and you also use debug mode to test your app. So, while testing you made sure no `null` value was getting passed so that in production mode there will be no `null` value. However, with Dart null safety, `assert` carries zero to no meaning.