# C assert() expressions

Tags: c, assert

assert() function working principle in C for me is like a dark forest. according to this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1571360, you can use the following construction to output the custom message to your assertion: `assert(retval == 1 && “retval is false”);`, so how does assert know that the expression with just a *binary and* actually contains a message **and** that it is not the part of the expression itself, and, also, which precompiler directives it uses in order to reveal the error's origin?

Comment: `assert` is not a function, it is a macro.

Comment: Note that `“` are not `"`, probably caused by a copy+paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does assert know that the expression with just a binary and actually contains a message and that it is not the part of the expression itself?

[Operator `#`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators) replaces the parameter of a macro by it's string representation.

```
#define TOSTRING(parameter)  #parameter
//                            ^^^^^^^^^ - always followed by a macro parameter
//                           ^ - # operator

const char *a = TOSTRING(almost     anything does not matter !@#$%^&*./;[]);
// expands to:
// const char *a = "almost anything does not matter !@#$%^&*./;[]";
```

Using that operator, you can take the input from a macro and pass it to your function as a string:

```
#define myassert(expression)   myassert_handle(expression, #expression)

void myassert_handle(bool expression_result, const char *exprsesion_string) {
   if (expression_result == false) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Och no: expression %s failed!\n", exprsesion_string);
       abort();
   }
}
```

That way:

```
myassert(retval == 1 && "retval is false");
// expands to
myassert_handle(retval == 1 && "retval is false", "retval == 1 && \"retval is false\"");
// and if the expression will fail, it will print: 
// Och no: expression retval == 1 && "retval is false" failed!
```

Assert macro also uses `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` [predefined macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros) and [`__func__`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_definition#func) to print a nice looking message where the assertion failed. And assert is usually implemented with [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) so that compiler can optimize it better.

Answer (score 3):

The message is part of the expression, so the assert won't know that the message is not the part of the expression.

When `retval == 1` is false, `retval == 1 && (something)` is evaluated as false without evaluating `(something)`.

When `retval == 1` is true, `"retval is false"` is evaluated and, because it is converted to a valid pointer, it will also be evaluated as true, making `retval == 1 && "retval is false"` evaluated as true.

Therefore, the trueness of `retval == 1 && "retval is false"` is the same as `retval == 1`.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't "know". The string is a part of the expression and always evaluates to `true`. But if the first part of the expression is `false`, then the whole expression is `false` as well, and then per `man 3 assert`:

> If expression is false (i.e., compares equal to zero), assert()
> prints an error message to standard error and terminates the program
> by calling abort(3).  The error message includes the name of the file
> and function containing the assert() call, the source code line
> number of the call, **and the text of the argument;**  something like:

> ```
>       prog: some_file.c:16: some_func: Assertion `val == 0' failed.
> ```

The emphasis is mine, and is showing that the message will in fact contain the message string. Similar to:

```
prog: some_file.c:16: some_func: Assertion `val == 0 && "The message text"' failed.
```