# Styles of dealing with errors in C?

Tags: c, error-handling, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error handling in C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385975/error-handling-in-c-code)

Hello people. I'm using C for some small projects and I see how, because it doesn't have dedicated error handling constructs, I have to pollute my algorithm with extra conditional blocks. My question is how do you prefer to deal with errors, and justification why. I'm torn between two ways... if you have a third one, post it. Thanks.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////
// method 1

// stuff that can go wrong;

if (test1 == failed)
{
    // print error;
    // exit;
}
else
{
    // more stuff that can go wrong;

    if (test2 == failed)
    {
        // print error;
        // exit;
    }
    else
    {
        // ... and so on...
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////
// method 2

// stuff that can go wrong;

if (test1 == failed)
{
    // print error;
    // exit;
}

// more stuff that can go wrong;

if (test2 == failed)
{
    // print error;
    // exit;
}

// ... and so on...
```

Comment: I would suggest using the second style, since it does not affect your intendation. But I guess thats just tase.

Answer (score 5):

Some people won't agree with me on this, but I use goto's. Inside each function, at the end I have a block at the end which looks like this

```
if (0)
{
ERROR:
  // Handle errors, and exit/return after potentially freeing resources
}
```

Then I use `if (something_bad) goto ERROR;` without elses or other stuff.

Many people don't like goto's, but this is the way to do this instead of duplicating code. If you really insist on not using goto's I'd do this:

```
#define LOCAL_ASSERT(COND) if (COND) { \
  /* Handle errors, and exit/return after potentially freeing resources */ \
}
```

Add a define for it at the begining of each function, and then add add a `#undef LOCAL_ASSERT` at the end of the function. This allows for different error handling at each function, without polluting the entire program with different macro names.

Then I simply use `LOCAL_ASSERT(cond)` everywhere.

**Edit:** to make myself clearer, this is to save writing the error handling code many times. If you want small customizations, it's easy to set an error variable string (or add it as a macro parameter). I simply don't like the if else things. I usually do

```
// method 1
if (error) goto ERROR; // no else

// method 2
LOCAL_ASSERT(cond);
```

Elses do pollute your code and require more indentation which is sometimes annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's user preference somewhat, but I try really hard to establish a *single* exit point from each function, or at most, two exit points (but they must be obvious and easy to breakpoint):

```
const Bool funcFoo(int someval, int someval2, int someval3)
{
  if(someval == okval)
  { // We're ok
    if(someval2 == okval2)
    { // Still ok.
      if(someval3 == okval3)
      { // Yippee!  We made it!
        return True;  // <===== ONLY SUCCESS RETURN POINT
      }
    }
  }
  // Houston, we had a problem.
  return False;  // <===== ONLY FAIL RETURN POINT
}
```

In the case where the "`else`" matters, it's a similar unwrapping, but we maintain ONLY two return points:

```
const Bool funcFoo(int someval, int someval2, int someval3)
{
  if(someval == okval)
  { // We're ok
    if(someval2 == okval2)
    { // Still ok.
      if(someval3 == okval3)
      { // Yippee!  We made it!
        return True;  // <===== ONLY SUCCESS RETURN POINT
      }
      else
      { // someval3 is bad.
        //...maybe handle, not return.
      }
    }
    else
    { // someval2 is bad.
      // ...maybe handle, not return.
    }
  }
  else
  { // someval is bad.
    // ...maybe handle, not return.
  }
  // Houston, we had a problem.
  return False;  // <===== ONLY FAIL RETURN POINT
}
```

A couple things to mention:

1. One return point is best.  Two
   return points are acceptable if they
   are obvious (your errors typically mandate a return, or a failure-to-go-on).
2. Sometimes the "`else`" is for
   debugging purposes only, at which
   point I wrap them in `#ifdef _DEBUG ... #endif`
3. Sometimes the "test" should be for
   success, and sometimes for failure,
   depending on which is most
   appropriate for nesting.
4. This approach (nested testing) is
   sometimes tied to sequential
   testing.  However, nested testing is
   generally preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use something like this:

```
if (test1 == failed)
{
    // print error;
    // exit;
}
else if (test2 == failed)
{
    // print error;
    // exit;
}
else
{
    // ... and so on...
}
```

It's more readable and it limits indentation. It also clearly shows me that if one condition fails, it's going to try all others until it finally fails; there's no chance of having 2 conditions fulfilled at the same time.

Comment: There are however `more stuff that can go wrong` so you can't really do this in a nice way.

Comment: There's always more stuff that can go wrong :).

Answer (score 0):

I vote for method 2. As you mention, the error handling in method 1 obscures the logic of the "real" algorithm.