# C handling error states

Tags: c, error-handling

I'm writing program in C and I have function `handleError(int errcode)` available.
All it does is unallocate all memory space and call `exit(errcode)`.

In program I have 2 options.

1. Have all functions return error code to caller. Do the full chain of handling returned error codes to `main` and handle it here.
2. Have most of functions returning `void` and call `handleError` whenever the error occurs and program has to be stoped.

What is more readable, manageable, and performance-wise choice?

Our team is not united in this matter and I need some outside view on this.

EDIT:

I am gonna add few informations. Errors will be rare and none of errors detected that way will be recoverable.

Comment: Go for solution 1. In case you might reuse your code one day, or your project grows, you'd sure regret it if having gone for 2.

Comment: "C handling errors" is something of an oxymoron -- there never has been a good way, just different compromises.  The best choice (of several poor choices) will depend in large part on the overall style of programming, how often interfaces return error conditions, how detailed you want to be in error reporting, how much you're willing to sacrifice convenience for robustness, etc.

Comment: Hint: Consider writing some macros to simplify return code checking, if you go that way.

Comment: By the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385975/error-handling-in-c-code (Note both the accepted and top-voted answers)

Answer (score 2):

I just posted a somehow [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322137/c-library-for-logging-warnings-error-reporting). I just wanted to mention the [UDI](http://www.project-udi.org/) way of handling errors:

- allocate an error structure that you pass down to the functions you call
- in case of error / warning **each** function adds its own error to the structure

In this way you may trace the error and see various components reacting to that error.

Bottom line: 1.