# How do the languages without exceptions present failure?

Tags: exception, programming-languages, theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error handling in C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385975/error-handling-in-c-code)

I mean, I guess not all languages have exceptions so how I e.g. in C will find out more about a failure?

Answer (score 0):

Return error codes from your functions, or a boolean indicating success/failure.