# C error handling withing an application

Tags: c, error-handling

The post [Error handling in C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385975/error-handling-in-c-code) describes the error handling in C library, however I'm wondering how to handle errors within your own application.

I'm about to write my first C application, and I'm considering of two error handling styles: returning error code and returning error messages.

```
// error code style
#define INTERNAL_ERROR 3
int foo(void)
{
   int rc = third_party_lib_func();
   if (rc) {
       return INTERNAL_ERROR;
       // pro: looks nice and clean, everyone talks about error code
       // con: it is hard to debug, what error comes from the third 
       // party function?
   }
   return 0;
}

// error message style
char *foo(void)
{
    int rc = third_party_lib_func();
    if (rc) {
        char *errstr = third_party_lib_strerror(rc);
        return errstr;
        // pro: golang style, easy to check by foo() == NULL,
        //      easy to debug
        // con: maybe it is an rare error handling approach?
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

What is your opinion? And I'm wondering what is the most common way used in the real world application? Thanks.

Comment: "What is your opinion?" - Bad juju. Such questions are off-topic.

Comment: IMO, codes are better.  Returning messages directly means more difficult maintenance and problems with internationalization.

Comment: @Olaf every answer on stackoverflow is based on someone's opinion, why bad?

Comment: @nut: You wouldn't ask if you have taken the tour and learned [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually prefer error codes. If you're interested in proper error handling in C, I recommend reading the [CERT secure coding recommendations and rules](https://securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6619150) .

Additionally to return error codes I tend to use logging. For example the following macros.

```
/* defining some error logging macros */
#define LOG_ERROR(...)            \
  do {                            \
    errx(1, __VA_ARGS__);         \
  } while(0)

#define LOG_WARNING(...)          \
  do {                            \
    warnx(__VA_ARGS__);           \
  } while(0)
```

A return case could look like

```
if (!something) {
   LOG_WARNING("Something bad happend");
   return (-1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is very difficult to find articles about C error handling on the Internet.

Comment: @nut you're welcome :) btw: another nice site is http://c-faq.com/

Comment: thanks, great link