# What to return from function that returns a struct type in case of error?

Tags: c, memory

I'm implementing a queue in C and, following general advice of using as little dynamic memory as possible, have the following for my nodes:

```
struct qnode {
    struct message_t message;
    struct qnode* next;
};

struct message_t {
    char prefix[BUF_SIZE];
    char command[CMD_MAXLEN];
    char params[MAX_PARAMS][BUF_SIZE];
};
```

---

Since I'm only dealing with `message_t`s and not pointers to them, my dequeue function has the following signature:

```
struct message_t dequeue(struct message_q* q);
```

Is there a convention on what to return from this type of function if there is an error (in my case, what if the queue is empty)? For now, I'm returning a `struct message_t` with all fields set to "0".

My other alternative would be to use pointers to `message_t` everywhere, and then return `NULL` in case of error. I'd like to know the pros and cons of each approach, as well as some of the best practices in my specific case.

Comment: The convention is change it to `bool dequeue(struct message_q* q, struct message_t* out)`

Comment: See [Error handling in C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385975/error-handling-in-c-code) for a comprehensive discussion of options.  You will probably do best with a return code indicating success or failure and returning the result via a pointer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I would consider that a duplicate. You, it seems, not. Why?

Comment: @Yunnosch: not quite confident enough to wield Mjölnir single-handedly on it.  It discusses general error strategies and only coincidentally functions that return structures (as opposed to pointers to structures).  However, with the confirmation from someone else that it isn't a bad choice of duplicate, I'm willing to hammer it closed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I see. I forgot that with great power comes great responsibility (or that you of course have that power). I respect your decision not to hammer too soon very much. I realise I should just have expressed my opinion with a close vote.

Comment: @Yunnosch: If you'd voted to close as duplicate (of the question I mentioned) and I'd been attracted back by some means (such as a comment), I'd have closed as a duplicate.  So some comment to me was not completely out of order — and did end up with the desired effect.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the first couple of comments here were exactly the answer I was looking for (and couldn’t find anywhere before asking). While the question you linked has a good discussion of general error handling in C projects, it does not address the specific nuance of my question regarding my want to use static memory as opposed to pointers

Answer (score 0):

This won't be a complete solution for you, but something like this would be very re-usable going ahead. 
I have a small task (not in RTOS context) handler for a non-OS based uController firmware. I prefer it done this way. Suppose I have a set of functions which add/delete tasks to a queue, checks if queue is full/empty, check if task is present in the queue or not, etc.

```
typedef enum {

    Q_SUCCESS = 1,
    Q_FULL,
    Q_EMPTY,
    Q_TASKDUPLICATE,
    Q_TASKNOTFOUND,
    MAX_QSTATES,
    Q_FAILURE = -1,

} eQStates_t ;

eQStates_t Queue_AddTask(eTasks_t Task);
eQStates_t Queue_DiscardTask0(void);
bool_t Queue_GetOccurance(eTasks_t Task);
```

To give you an example of how they are being used, lets pick a function.

```
eQStates_t Queue_DiscardTask0(void)
{
    uint32_t iLoop = 0;

    // Check if the count is zero, should never be the case as an Idle task is always there, adding itself into the queue
    if(0 == Queue_GetCount())
    {
        return Q_EMPTY;
    }

    // Discard the position 0 Task from the queue

    // Shift the whole queue

    // Add Idle task to the end of the queue

    return Q_SUCCESS;
}
```

I agree that this isn't a very intelligent code to set as an example, but may be this could give an idea about how you could use the similar kind of implementation.