# cgo: How to prevent "multiple definition..." error when using cgo to include a C header file in a package?

Tags: c, go, linker, cgo

I'm writing a native library which provides a C api using cgo. I have a C header file which includes a constant definition, but when I include this in a package using cgo, and then import this package into main in go, I get a `multiple definition...` linker error on build:

```
C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-1146178960\000011.o:C:\Temp\cgo-error\mypackage/errors.h:29: multiple definition of `MYMODULE_ERROR_STRS'; C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-1146178960\000010.o:C:/Temp/cgo-error/mypackage/errors.h:29: first defined here    
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The example code below uses the error handling sample given in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59221452/1324919

main.go:

```
package main

import "C"
import "example.com/cgo-error/mypackage"

func main() {}

//export exported_function
func exported_function() {
    mypackage.CallCFunction()
}
```

mypackage.go (includes the C header file):

```
package mypackage

// #include "errors.h"
import "C"

func CallCFunction() {
    _ = C.mymodule_func1()
}
```

errors.h:

```
#ifndef ERRORS_H_
#define ERRORS_H_

/// @brief Error codes for library "mymodule"
typedef enum mymodule_error_e
{
    /// No error
    MYMODULE_ERROR_OK = 0,
    MYMODULE_ERROR_INVARG,
    MYMODULE_ERROR_NOMEM,
    MYMODULE_ERROR_MYERROR,
    MYMODULE_ERROR_COUNT,
} mymodule_error_t;

// Array of strings to map enum error types to printable strings
const char *const MYMODULE_ERROR_STRS[] =
    {
        "MYMODULE_ERROR_OK",
        "MYMODULE_ERROR_INVARG",
        "MYMODULE_ERROR_NOMEM",
        "MYMODULE_ERROR_MYERROR",
};

// To get a printable error string
const char *mymodule_error_str(mymodule_error_t err);

// Other functions in mymodule
mymodule_error_t mymodule_func1(void);
mymodule_error_t mymodule_func2(void);
mymodule_error_t mymodule_func3(void);

#endif
```

errors.c:

```
#include "errors.h"
#include <stdio.h>

/// @brief      Function to get a printable string from an enum error type
/// @param[in]  err     a valid error code for this module
/// @return     A printable C string corresponding to the error code input above, or NULL if an invalid error code
///             was passed in
const char *mymodule_error_str(mymodule_error_t err)
{
    const char *err_str = NULL;

    // Ensure error codes are within the valid array index range
    if (err >= MYMODULE_ERROR_COUNT)
    {
        goto done;
    }

    err_str = MYMODULE_ERROR_STRS[err];

done:
    return err_str;
}

// Let's just make some empty dummy functions to return some errors; fill these in as appropriate for your
// library module

mymodule_error_t mymodule_func1(void)
{
    return MYMODULE_ERROR_OK;
}

mymodule_error_t mymodule_func2(void)
{
    return MYMODULE_ERROR_INVARG;
}

mymodule_error_t mymodule_func3(void)
{
    return MYMODULE_ERROR_MYERROR;
}
```

It looks to me that having the header file included in `mypackage.go` and also including it in `errors.c` causes it to be imported twice by the go linker when `mypackage` is imported in `main`.
Is there anyway to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not **define** variables in your .h files as you will a new instance of those variables in every compilation unit which `#include` this .h file It is the source of your problem. Place them in the C file.

In the ***errors.h*** file:

```
extern const char *const MYMODULE_ERROR_STRS[];
```

and the actual definition in the ***errors.c:*** file:

```
const char *const MYMODULE_ERROR_STRS[] =
    {
        "MYMODULE_ERROR_OK",
        "MYMODULE_ERROR_INVARG",
        "MYMODULE_ERROR_NOMEM",
        "MYMODULE_ERROR_MYERROR",
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this resolves the issue. I had tried to do this previously, but I neglected to add `extern` to the declaration in errors.h, so I received the same error.